# postgres copy table to table - what to do with the serial?

Tags: postgresql, insert

I have to tables with identical columns. In both cases the first column is called id and type of SERIAL.
I want to copy the content of the second to the first table. I want to copy everything except the id. If I do this:

```
INSERT INTO first
SELECT *
FROM second;
```

It will complain, because it will duplicate the id. 
If I do this:

```
INSERT INTO first
SELECT 1col, 2col, 3col .... (every column except the id column, which I dont want to be copied)
FROM second;
```

It will complain because it tries to insert the value of the '1col' into id column.

> ERROR:  column "id" is of type bigint but expression is of type date

So the bottom line is I want copy EVERYTHING except the SERIAL value, which needs to be calculated by the receiving table. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were half way there.

```
INSERT INTO first (1col, 2col, 3col ....)
SELECT 1col, 2col, 3col ....
FROM second
```

Yes, you have to repeat all the columns. No, there's no way to say "all except id".